# Invalid GeoJSON geometry when using GEE assets with .filterBounds GEE python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm trying to import cloud assets (shapefiles) from GEE in order to use them in the GEE python API.
I used the ee.data.getAsset() function with the path of the cloud assets. When I print the result I got this :
`{'type': 'TABLE', 'name': 'projects/ee-alengrand121/assets/Lake_Tanganyika', 'id': 'projects/ee-alengrand121/assets/Lake_Tanganyika', 'updateTime': '2023-10-22T09:13:57.697780Z', 'sizeBytes': '12438'}`

And when I tried to use the .filterBounds function with the imported asset I got this error : Invalid GeoJSON geometry
I tried to do asset.geometry() but got the same error : Invalid GeoJSON geometry.

I used those assets on GEE and don't have any problem with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAsset` just gets metadata about the asset; it doesn't actually load it.
In order to use it, you use the FeatureCollection constructor with the asset's ID/path.

```
ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-alengrand121/assets/Lake_Tanganyika")
```